# How to easily extend a typescript object with it's contract described by an interface

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a **CustomError** interface which extends the ES6 **Error** one, adding a **custom** property.

```
interface CustomError extends Error {
  custom: string;
}
```

Now, I create a ES6 Error:

```
const error = new Error('something wrong');
```

And, in order to create the custom Error, i execute the following function:

```
const customError = createCustomError(error);
```

The createCustomError function uses Typescript's **as** syntax:

```
function createCustomError(error: Error): CustomError {
  const customError = error as CustomError;
  customError.custom = 'Custom';
  return customError;
}
```

This method is really easy and terse, but **I am not sure it's the way to go** because, it's the **responsibility of this function to actually set the custom property**.
If it doesn't, I will have no type safety.

What do you think, should I do it like this and capture the danger through a unit test? Making sure **all the CustomErrors have their custom properties set**?

Or is it a better way?

**This started from a frustration, because, the other way of doing this, which i know, seems to be over complicated and involves saucery.**

```
export class BodyParserError extends Error {
  type: string;
  status: number;
  name: ErrorNames.BODY_PARSER_ERROR = ErrorNames.BODY_PARSER_ERROR;

  constructor(...args: any[]) {
    super(...args);
    this.message = args[0].message;
    this.type = args[0].type;
    this.status = args[0].status;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, BodyParserError);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, BodyParserError.prototype);
  }
}

export const createBodyParserError = (error): BodyParserError => new BodyParserError(error);
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, it's pretty common to see such `create*` functions that internally do some unsafe type assertions to change the type of an object.

Comment: @Titian, would you recommend the 1st method? My gut tells me I should take the risk if I unit test it :)

Comment: Yeah, the fist method is fine in my opinion, as far as that goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to extend objects in TypeScript is by using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
interface CustomError extends Error {
  custom: string;
}

const customError: CustomError = Object.assign(
    new Error('error message'), 
    { custom: 'custom message' }
);
```

`Object.assign()` is typed more or less properly in the system library, so if you for example forget to initialize or misspell some property you will get an error

```
const badCustomError: CustomError = Object.assign(
    new Error('error message'),
    { customm: 'custom message' }
);

// error: Property 'custom' is missing in type 'Error & { customm: string; }'
```

Comment: Hi artem and ty for your answer! The problem is the object assign does shallow copying, and in this case, only the message of the error gets copied. I am not sure if even the message, because i think it's not enumerable. So this is a no-go imo :(

Comment: No it does not, it returns the first object that you pass to `Object.assign()` which in this case will be the intact `Error` object with only one property added. At least that's how I interpret the documentation that says "Return value: target object".

Comment: Also, all the properties of `Error` object are non-enumerable: `Object.keys(new Error('foo'))` prints `[]`. Was a surprise for me too.

Comment: By the way it's really easy to check in the browser console: `const d = new Error('foo');`, then `Object.assign(d, {custom: 'bar'}) === d;` prints `true`

Comment: `Object.assign` does a shallow copy, but @artem is correct: this solution will copy the custom message into the Error object.

Comment: Yes, when used with `{}` as its first argument, the result is a shallow copy of the second object.